# two different user controls in same asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, web-user-controls

this is my application link please [download](http://www.mediafire.com/?zyncso3qi0k6pqi)

i had 2 different user controls in one .aspx page.

first user control was dropdownlist binded with database. 
second user control was gridview.

if i select a company int the dropdownlist products of that company should be displayed in the second user control.

**my problem was,** when i am selecting the companies in the dropdownlist gridview user control is loading first and 2nd dropdownlist selected event is firing..

please help me...

Comment: instead of giving the link. show the code where you are facing the issue.

Comment: Don't load your usercontrols by handling the page_load event. Instead lazy load them by a method when needed. Then you can handle a custom event from the ddl-usercontrol in the page to call the `BindGridView` method in usercontrol2.

Comment: with design time i am adding the two controls. how to add custom event to bind the gridview. pleaase help i a new to user controls.

Comment: @varaprasadreddy: I have currently not the time to provide a complete answer, so have a look at this link: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8797/Mastering-Page-UserControl-Communication#4.3 1.) Raise a custom event on SelectedIndexChanged of the DropDownList in UC1 2.) Handle this event in the page 3.) Call a method in UC2 that databinds the GridView.

Comment: Tim Schmelter thanks for the rely.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably check the `IsPostBack` property and only populate the controls if it isn't a postback.

```
void Page_Load()
{
  if (!IsPostBack)
  {
    // Populate the user controls.
  }
}
```

But since you didn't show any code I'm just guessing.

Comment: i got the solution here is the link http://reddyinfosoft.blogspot.in/2012/05/interaction-between-two-user-controls.html#more